# DataTable (Server Side) Ajax using CodeIgniter4 Error DataTable not showing

Tags: php, codeigniter, datatable

So I have been tasked to make a DataTable using codeigniter 4 and was surfing on the internet on how to do it, I manage to find a tutorial on youtube and followed each of the steps but for some reason the datatable on the server side isn't showing the table

{"draw":0,"recordsTotal":10,"recordsFiltered":10,"data":[{"id":"5","nama":"Hallie Dickinson","telp":"1","alamat":"899 Mohammed Mount Apt. 571\nNorth Kaylee, RI 54613-4975","email":"justina.glover@hotmail.com","position":"Manager"},{"id":"2","nama":"Jack Mante","telp":"831","alamat":"85307 Annamarie Extension\nKaylieshire, OR 19174-5549","email":"hrath@yahoo.com","position":"Manager"},{"id":"3","nama":"Jed Oberbrunner","telp":"534","alamat":"744 Dicki Groves\nWolffchester, ND 29161","email":"gstoltenberg@stoltenberg.com","position":"IT"},{"id":"10","nama":"Joel Stamm","telp":"0","alamat":"4619 Spinka Parkways Suite 356\nLake Bryce, DE 88639","email":"hill.adaline@gleichner.info","position":"HRD"},{"id":"8","nama":"Lorena Veum","telp":"812249","alamat":"88883 Dayna Cliff Suite 269\nEricside, KY 35382-6163","email":"chaya.walter@wyman.com","position":"IT"},{"id":"6","nama":"Mrs. Betty Kreiger Sr.","telp":"661","alamat":"762 Bailey Crescent\nMatildaborough, OK 22163","email":"kiehn.nelson@quigley.com","position":"Intern"},{"id":"4","nama":"Myron Okuneva","telp":"1","alamat":"29794 Barton Crescent\nSouth Vance, NE 81019","email":"klocko.dion@gmail.com","position":"IT"},{"id":"7","nama":"Prof. Lionel Ankunding DDS","telp":"0","alamat":"1516 Armand Oval Suite 127\nPort Stuart, AR 95802-1447","email":"apfeffer@rau.biz","position":"Manager"},{"id":"1","nama":"Prof. Pete Turner V","telp":"1","alamat":"4236 Bashirian Stream\nMannland, AR 84138","email":"camden08@rice.com","position":"Manager"},{"id":"9","nama":"Wilson Johns","telp":"229313","alamat":"8992 Jonathon Port\nHopeland, PA 66858","email":"lily57@gmail.com","position":"IT"}]}

This is the result it gave me

- here is my model:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use CodeIgniter\Model;

class ModelKaryawan extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'karyawan';
    public function searchAndDisplay($keyword = null, $start = 0, $length = 0)
    {
        $builder = $this->table('karyawan');
        if ($keyword) {
            $arr_keyword = explode(" ", $keyword);
            for ($i = 0; $i < count($arr_keyword); $i++) {
                $builder = $builder->orLike('nama', $arr_keyword[$i]);
                $builder = $builder->orLike('telp', $arr_keyword[$i]);
                $builder = $builder->orLike('alamat', $arr_keyword[$i]);
                $builder = $builder->orLike('email', $arr_keyword[$i]);
                $builder = $builder->orLike('position', $arr_keyword[$i]);
            }
        }
        if ($start != 0 or $length != 0) {
            $builder = $builder->limit((int)$length, (int)$start);
        }

        return $builder->orderBy('nama')->get()->getResult();
    }
}
```

- here is my controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Controllers;

use \Hermawan\DataTables\DataTable;

use App\Models\ModelKaryawan;

class Karyawan extends BaseController
{
    protected $db, $builder, $ModelKaryawan;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->db      = \Config\Database::connect();
        $this->builder = $this->db->table('users');
        $this->ModelKaryawan = new ModelKaryawan();
    }

    public function karyawanAjax() //Server Side (Ajax)
    {
        $param['draw'] = isset($_REQUEST['draw']) ? $_REQUEST['draw'] : '';
        $start = isset($_REQUEST['start']) ? $_REQUEST['start'] : '';
        $length = isset($_REQUEST['length']) ? $_REQUEST['length'] : '';
        $search_value = isset($_REQUEST['search']['value']) ? $_REQUEST['search']['value'] : '';

        $data = $this->ModelKaryawan->searchAndDisplay($search_value, $start, $length);
        $total_count = $this->ModelKaryawan->searchAndDisplay($search_value);

        $json_data = array(
            'draw' => intval($param['draw']),
            'recordsTotal' => count($total_count),
            'recordsFiltered' => count($total_count),
            'data' => $data

        );
        echo json_encode($json_data);
    }
}
```

- Here is my view

```
<title>Data table ajax</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/2.0.1/css/dataTables.dataTables.css">

<table class="table" id="example">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">#</th>
            <th scope="col">Nama</th>
            <th scope="col">Telp</th>
            <th scope="col">Alamat</th>
            <th scope="col">Email</th>
            <th scope="col">Position</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.2/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/2.0.1/js/dataTables.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#example').DataTable({
            'processing': true,
            'serverSide': true,
            'serverMethod': 'post',
            "ajax": "<?= site_url('Karyawan/karyawanAjax') ?>",
            "columns": [{`your text`
                "data": "nama"
            }, {
                "data": "telp"
            }, {
                "data": "alamat"
            }, {
                "data": "email"
            }, {
                "data": "position"
            }]
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Have you checked the browser console for any related error messages?

Comment: As @Marleen said, you have a random string in your JS code, and as Cbroe said, you have to check the console for any errors.

I just wanted to recommend this package to use datatables in CI4: https://codeigniter4-datatables.hermawan.dev/

Answer (score 0):

You have a random `your text` string in your DataTable columns, and you're missing the `id` column. Try the following:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#example').DataTable({
            'processing': true,
            'serverSide': true,
            'serverMethod': 'post',
            "ajax": "<?= site_url('Karyawan/karyawanAjax') ?>",
            "columns": [{
                "data": "id"
            }, {
                "data": "nama"
            }, {
                "data": "telp"
            }, {
                "data": "alamat"
            }, {
                "data": "email"
            }, {
                "data": "position"
            }]
        });
    });
</script>
```